# CQWP - How to force CommonViewFields to display all fields

Tags: sharepoint, caml, cqwp

I'm using a **CQWP**(Content query web part) that fetch a calendar list and I want to filter my result (customqueryoverride - usign CAML). However, some fields from the calendar list are hidden to me.

**I want to know all fields in my calendar list**.

The solution I came up with was to use an identity transform XSL to display all my properties and their values and adding all fields to the **CommonViewFields** property.

```
<property name="CommonViewFields" type="string">
  EventDate,DateTime;EndDate,DateTime;fRecurrence,Boolean
</property>
```

The issue I have is that I dont know the field name... **Any wildcard I could use?**(`%%%` and `***` didn't work) *Any other way of getting all the fields name would work too.*

***Note***: *It's to understand and play with recurrent events*.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SharePoint 2010 Manager (http://spm.codeplex.com/) tool.  It gives you a plethora of details about your SharePoint platform at all levels, right down to the fields in a list.  It will give you all the field details, including the internal name you need to use for CommonViewFields.

Answer (score 1):

To print all available field names in CQWP the following XSLT could be used:

```
<xsl:for-each select="@*">
            Field Name :<xsl:value-of select="name()" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

It should be placed in ItemStyle.xsl inside template that is used to item rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Use  tag for this, comment the main template in main XSL and add this as template match="/":

```
<xsl:template match="/ ">  
<textarea cols="50" rows="15" dir="ltr">
   <xmp><xsl:copy-of select="*"/></xmp> 
</textarea>
```

Now the CQWP will display the full query response XML